# Manipulation of tab delimited file for top 5 values based and printing adjacent columns values with it

Tags: r, dplyr, desctools

I have a tab delimited file `abc.txt`

```
contig  score   guide
1:100-101   7   AAA
1:100-101   6   BBB
1:100-101   5   CCC
1:100-101   4   DDD
1:100-101   3   EEE
1:100-101   2   FFF
1:100-101   1   GGG
1:100-101   90  HHH
1:100-101   111 III
1:100-101   1111    JJJ
1:200-203   503.5333333 KKK
1:200-203   570.7212121 LLL
1:200-203   637.9090909 MMM
1:200-203   705.0969697 NNN
1:200-203   772.2848485 OOO
1:200-203   839.4727273 PPP
1:200-203   906.6606061 QQQ
1:200-203   973.8484848 RRR
2:300-301   1041.036364 SSS
2:300-301   1108.224242 TTT
2:300-301   1175.412121 UUU
2:300-301   1242.6  VVV
2:300-301   1309.787879 ABC
2:300-301   1376.975758 CGA
2:300-301   1444.163636 ACD
```

Column 1-Contig has multiple repeat values, column two has scores and column three has guide letters corresponding to column-2 scores. I need to select top 5 scores for the similar values in column one (contig) and print there corresponding column 3 values.

Output should look like this, with first column having the unique column 1-Contig entry and next 10 rows for the top 5 scores and corresponding column-3 guide letters

```
    Score-1 Guide-1 Score-2 Guide-2 Score-3 Guide-3 Score-4 Guide-4 Score-5 Guide-5
1:100-101   1111    JJJ 111 III 90  HHH 7   AAA 6   BBB
1:200-203   973.8484848 RRR 906.6606061 QQQ 839.4727273 PPP 772.2848485 OOO 705.0969697 NNN
2:300-301   1444.163636 ACD 1376.975758 CGA 1309.787879 ABC 1242.6  VVV 1175.412121 UUU
```

I used "dplyr" and "desctools" packages, however I am running with some error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DescTools)
file <- "abc.txt"
x=read.table(file)
b <- Large(x, k=5, unique = FALSE, na.last=NA)
```

and getting this error

```
Error in Large(x, k = 5, unique = FALSE, na.last = NA) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
```

I was manged to do this in excel using 'sumproduct, large, iferror and vllokup' formulas, however for large datasets I want to extract file using R.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is large expects a numeric vector, not an entire dataframe.
This is just a guess since I dont have a reproducible example, but you might want to do something along these lines:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DescTools)
file <- "./abc.txt"
x=read.table(file)
colnames(x)<-c("contig","score","guide")
x<-x[-1,]

list <- split(x , f = x$contig )
columntitles<-c()
for (i in 1:5)
  columntitles<-c(columntitles,paste0("guide-",i),paste0("score-",i))
x = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 10)) 
colnames(x)<-columntitles

for (i in 1:3){
  singlerow<-c()
  partialdata<-list[[i]]
  partialdata<-partialdata%>% top_n(5, score)
  partialdata<-partialdata[Rev(order(partialdata$score)),]
  for (j in 1:5){
    singlerow<-c(singlerow,toString(partialdata$guide[j]),toString(partialdata$score[j]))

  }
  x<-rbind(x,singlerow)
}
x<-x[-1,]
```

Comment: I am having difficulty in getting dataframe wherein I have to account for similar contigs in column 1, as for each unique contig value i need those top 5 values.

Comment: In that case you want to first split them in a list according to contig, `list <- split( x , f = x$contig )` Then, you want to apply  `x<-x %>% top_n(5, score)` to each element in the list with a loop. Finally, you want to merge them all together (cbind or rbind).

Comment: If I loop it like `for (i in list) { x<-x %>% top_n(5, score)}` , getting following error  `Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: I've edited my original answer to provide you with a full script of what I meant. It's probably not the most line-efficient way of doing this, but it should be fairly simple to understand. You might need to change a few things, but it gives the exact output you need on my side.

Comment: Thanks! However it doesn't display the correponding contig in the output file.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to search for packages that solve this problem - base R has everything you need.

First we have to deal with the groupwise operation, so we split the data frame according to the groupvariable `contig` by means of the function `split()`. We get a list of data frames. In order to apply our operations to each of these we can use `lapply()`, which applies the given function to all the list elements. We build a function which selects the first 5 rows of the provided data frame `x`, ordered by `score` (descending with `-x$score`). We assign the result to `z`. The following `do.call(data.frame, split…)` structure only reshapes the result to the intended form.

The only thing that remains is to pack the list to a data frame and set the columnnames.

```
ll <- lapply(split(abc, abc$contig), function(x) {
      z <- x[order(-x$score)[1:5], 2:3]
      do.call(data.frame, split(z, 1:5))
    })

ll         # we're almost there …

$`1:100-101`
  X1.score X1.guide X2.score X2.guide X3.score X3.guide X4.score X4.guide X5.score X5.guide
10     1111      JJJ      111      III       90      HHH        7      AAA        6      BBB

$`1:200-203`
   X1.score X1.guide X2.score X2.guide X3.score X3.guide X4.score X4.guide X5.score X5.guide
    18 973.8485      RRR 906.6606      QQQ 839.4727      PPP 772.2848      OOO  705.097      NNN

$`2:300-301`
   X1.score X1.guide X2.score X2.guide X3.score X3.guide X4.score X4.guide X5.score X5.guide
25 1444.164      ACD 1376.976      CGA 1309.788      ABC   1242.6      VVV 1175.412      UUU

# … only pack the list to a data frame and set the columnnames
d.frm <- (do.call(rbind, ll))
colnames(d.frm) <- c(paste("Guide", 1:5), paste("Score", 1:5))[as.vector(t(matrix(1:10, nrow=5)))]

d.frm

            Guide 1 Score 1   Guide 2 Score 2   Guide 3 Score 3   Guide 4 Score 4  Guide 5 Score 5
1:100-101 1111.0000     JJJ  111.0000     III   90.0000     HHH    7.0000     AAA    6.000     BBB
1:200-203  973.8485     RRR  906.6606     QQQ  839.4727     PPP  772.2848     OOO  705.097     NNN
2:300-301 1444.1636     ACD 1376.9758     CGA 1309.7879     ABC 1242.6000     VVV 1175.412     UUU
```